# Why does VS code syntax highlighting becomes darker below some specific lines?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code for python programming and recently, the color of the syntax highlighting below some specific lines [became darker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx3L6.png).

This does not happen when the Python and Pylance extensions are not installed or [when I comment out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkJJj.png) the `from selenium import webdriver` line.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Visual Studio Code darkens the color on code which is unreachable. I am not familiar with the function you are using, but it will be easier to help if you can edit your question to include the code itself, rather than a screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The dimming of the text means that the code cannot be accessed, you can add configuration in *settings.json* to turn off the dimming function.

```json
        "editor.showUnused": false,
```

Or turn it off only in the python language.

```json
"[python]": {
        "editor.showUnused": false,
},
```

Comment: This explained odd behavior in my programs.  After reading this I went through my python code and found this shaded text.  I had accidentally placed a function inside the tab of a higher function and it couldn't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. I could by chance figure out this. Check if you have incomplete code like `raise Exception('This is the error message.')`, this is the cause in my case. After adding '#' in front of that line, all the codes following are as bright as above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happens when I create loops or conditional statements and some code blocks are not indented correctly.